# PDO FETCH_FUNC data as assoc array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to get data in PHP from PDO with some transformations of data during the fly. The best variants are `FETCH_CLASS` mode and `FETCH_FUNC` mode.

but the problem of `FETCH_CLASS` is that each property need to go throw `__set()` method to get transformation or at least to check if it needs transformation. And for 40K rows with 50 columns each it takes too much time.

`FETCH_FUNC` seems ideal for me cause i get all the columns of the row at once, can make some transforms BUT, the only problem is that i don't have column names cause column values come into function as parameters and the only way to get them is to call `func_get_args()`.

So generally the question is -> How can i get row data at once in some method of the class, function, using some combination of PDO FETCH modes as an assoc array, obj or some like columnName->columnValue structure? Using foreach after getting result is to long - i want to get transformed data already after calling pdo's `fetchAll()` method

Comment: Please see the scope that Stack Overflow allows.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you're overthinking this and are trying to be too clever. This will do just fine:

```
$data = [];
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = myTransformation($row);
}
```

In other words, just fetch with `FETCH_ASSOC`, then call your function on that result.